# What is the significance of "(k=v)"?

Tags: latex, auctex

When one uses `C-c C-e` to insert an environment such as `enumerate` in AUCTeX , one is presented with the prompt `(Optional) Options (k=v):` in the minibuffer.

I know that this is asking for options for the environment, but could someone please explain what the `(k=v)` means? It appears in certain environments' options prompts (e.g. `enumerate`, `itemize`), but not in others (e.g. `figure`, `tabular`). I couldn't find any explanation online. My AUCTeX version is 11.89, if that's important.

Comment: `k=v` stands for `key=value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some environments take options in the format `option_name=value`. For example, if you use the `enumitem` package, which replaces the built-in `enumerate` environment, you can get an enumeration using letters for the labels (in place of numbers) with the following code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*]
\item this is item "a"
\item another item, called "b"
\end{enumerate}
```

AuCTeX must have a list of which commonly used environments take options in the `k=v` format (like the `label=\alph*` above).